# Enabling Google Custom Search per blog in a community of blogs

Tags: google-custom-search

I have a site where when a user registers he gets a blog at **example.com/username**.

For example: user1 and user2 come to register. There would be two blogs at **example.com/user1** and **example.com/user2** respectively.

Will I be able to enable Google Custom Search for them individually?  So when someone visits **example.commysite.com/user1** and uses the search box there, the visitor only sees search results to user1's posts?

If so how do I do this?

Answer (score -1):

You could generate 2 google CSE for the two users and add the JS code into their page html files respectively.

After you defining the searching range for the two google CSE, you could let the visitor to search the specific results as you want.